# Obstructions to putting a complex structure on a real vector bundle (other than, obviously, dimension)

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

A complex vector bundle is usually described as one with structure group $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. If I take a real $2n$ when is it not the underlying real bundle of some complex bundle?

Comment: The bundle has to be orientable.

Comment: Dear @MichaelAlbanese, thanks that makes sense. Is there anything else or is that the sole requirement?

Comment: There's plenty of obstructions. Another is that the Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_{2i} \in H^{2i}(X;\Bbb Z/2)$ must lift to integral classes which I will mysteriously call $c_i \in H^{2i}(X;\Bbb Z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basic obstructions coming from [characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class), which come from looking at how the induced map of classifying spaces $BU(n) \to BO(2n)$ behaves on cohomology. Namely, the odd Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_{2i+1}$ must vanish, and as Mike Miller says in the comments, the even Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_{2i}$ must be the reduction of integral classes, namely the Chern classes $c_i$. Equivalently, the [integral Stiefel-Whitney classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Integral_Stiefel.E2.80.93Whitney_classes) $W_{2i+1} = \beta w_{2i}$ vanish, where $\beta$ is a [Bockstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bockstein_homomorphism).

Beyond this things get tricky, at least for me. I asked a question about this on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171904/obstructions-to-the-existence-of-stable-and-unstable-complex-structures).